# SQL : loop with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have to create a report that sums up days someone one has a case assigned to them, the only issue is that there are multiple rows. I need to calculate the difference when it gets assigned to someone else. there will be numerous cases and i wont know exactly how many times each case has been shifted to a different person.

example of the data

```
CaseId,CaseCounter,OldValue,NewValue,ChangeDate
399547,1, Brad, Eric, 9/18/2016
399547,2, Meghan, Joni, 9/19/2016
399547,3, Eric, Pam, 9/20/2016
399547,4, Pam, Meghan, 9/22/2016
399547,5, Joni, Eric, 9/25/2016
399547,6, Andrea, Team, 9/30/2016
399547,7, Team, Admin, 10/3/2016
399547,8, Admin, Brad, 10/19/2016
399547,9, Eric, Joni, 10/21/2016 - since this is the last record it should compare this to current date
460771,1, Meghan, Cheryl, 10/1/2016
460771,2, Admin, Meghan, 10/6/2016
460771,3, Admin, Cheryl, 10/6/2016
460771,4, Cheryl, Meghan ,10/9/2016
460771,5, Meghan, Admin, 10/11/2016

CREATE TABLE #Records (CaseID INT, caseCounter INT, oldValue VARCHAR(50),NewValue VARCHAR(50), changeDate DATETIME)
INSERT INTO #Records  ( CaseID ,caseCounter ,oldValue ,NewValue , changeDate)VALUES  (399547,1,'Brad','Eric','19/18/2016')
INSERT INTO #Records  ( CaseID ,caseCounter ,oldValue ,NewValue , changeDate)VALUES  (399547,2,'Meghan','Joni','9/19/2016')
INSERT INTO #Records  ( CaseID ,caseCounter ,oldValue ,NewValue , changeDate)VALUES  (399547,3,'Eric','Pam','9/20/2016')
INSERT INTO #Records  ( CaseID ,caseCounter ,oldValue ,NewValue , changeDate)VALUES  (399547,4,'Pam','Meghan','9/22/2016')
INSERT INTO #Records  ( CaseID ,caseCounter ,oldValue ,NewValue , changeDate)VALUES  (399547,5,'Joni','Eric','9/25/2016')
INSERT INTO #Records  ( CaseID ,caseCounter ,oldValue ,NewValue , changeDate)VALUES  (399547,6,'Andrea','Team','9/30/2016')
INSERT INTO #Records  ( CaseID ,caseCounter ,oldValue ,NewValue , changeDate)VALUES  (399547,7,'Team','Admin','10/3/2016')
INSERT INTO #Records  ( CaseID ,caseCounter ,oldValue ,NewValue , changeDate)VALUES  (399547,8,'Admin','Brad','10/19/2016')
INSERT INTO #Records  ( CaseID ,caseCounter ,oldValue ,NewValue , changeDate)VALUES  (399547,9,'Eric','Joni','10/21/2016')
INSERT INTO #Records  ( CaseID ,caseCounter ,oldValue ,NewValue , changeDate)VALUES  (460771,1,'Meghan','Cheryl','10/1/2016')
INSERT INTO #Records  ( CaseID ,caseCounter ,oldValue ,NewValue , changeDate)VALUES  (460771,2,'Admin','Meghan','10/6/2016')
INSERT INTO #Records  ( CaseID ,caseCounter ,oldValue ,NewValue , changeDate)VALUES  (460771,3,'Admin','Cheryl','10/6/2016')
INSERT INTO #Records  ( CaseID ,caseCounter ,oldValue ,NewValue , changeDate)VALUES  (460771,4,'Cheryl','Meghan','42652')
INSERT INTO #Records  ( CaseID ,caseCounter ,oldValue ,NewValue , changeDate)VALUES  (460771,5,'Meghan','Admin','10/11/2016')
```

the expected outcome is

```
CaseID UseID DayCount
399547 Eric  6
399547 Pam   2
399547 Joni  13 (1 + diff (10/21-today) =12)
```

Comment: *Please* format your data...

Comment: You have `UseID` in your expected outcome and not in your example data - yet you include no information on how that field is to be calculated/derived.

Comment: It's not a loop, you just need some aggregate functions, tell us wich DB you use.

Comment: What is start date for process and what is 19/18/2016?

Comment: The create and insert scripts you just added don't add any value. How about answering the question... which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL server 2008

Comment: @Nicarus Create and inserts are much better than previous data to recreate case

Comment: @Kacper - Maybe "no value" was an exaggeration, but I'd rather have the DBMS as well as the attempt at a solution.

Comment: @Nicarus sure that's more important but we have it now ;)

Comment: @Kacper - Not whatever OP has attempted, no.

Comment: @ nicarus The useID is basically the newvalue, it list who had the case at that time. the old value shows who the case came from, since I just need to know how long someone had the case, as long as i can do the diff between, i shouldn't need to track the old value

Comment: Thank you in advance for taking a look so quickly, this is a great community

Comment: @obaidulkhandaker - Can you post the code you have written so far? Maybe we can help you fix or improve that? Otherwise, you are essentially asking us to write the code for you from scratch.

Comment: @Nicarus Honestly i dont even know where to start on this, i have tried case statements with no success

Comment: Post whatever you have tried. It is much better than nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. The code first creates a temporary view of the #Records table via use of a common table expression (CTE) to allow the table to be compared to itself.  The CTE is joined to `#Records` on the `CaseID` and on the `caseCounter`, less 1 (i.e. `caseCounter` 2 from the CTE is joined to `caseCounter` 1 of the `#Records` table), thus allowing the next date to be populated on the older record.  Then a simple `datediff` is performed to get the days it was held, and then a summary is calculated.

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#Records') is not null 
drop table #records

CREATE TABLE #Records (CaseID INT, caseCounter INT, oldValue VARCHAR(50),NewValue VARCHAR(50), changeDate DATE)
INSERT INTO #Records 
VALUES 
(399547,1,'Brad','Eric','9/18/2016'),
(399547,2,'Meghan','Joni','9/19/2016'),
(399547,3,'Eric','Pam','9/20/2016'),
(399547,4,'Pam','Meghan','9/22/2016'),
(399547,5,'Joni','Eric','9/25/2016'),
(399547,6,'Andrea','Team','9/30/2016'),
(399547,7,'Team','Admin','10/3/2016'),
(399547,8,'Admin','Brad','10/19/2016'),
(399547,9,'Eric','Joni','10/21/2016'),
(460771,1,'Meghan','Cheryl','10/1/2016'),
(460771,2,'Admin','Meghan','10/6/2016'),
(460771,3,'Admin','Cheryl','10/6/2016'),
(460771,4,'Cheryl','Meghan','10/9/2016'),
(460771,5,'Meghan','Admin','10/11/2016');


IF object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null 
drop table #temp; -- drops temp table if already exists, improves ability to re-run code.

-- CTE created, whic his just a copy of the table to compare against itself

WITH CTE
AS (
SELECT 
CaseID
,caseCounter 
,oldValue 
,NewValue
,changeDate AS NewDate
FROM #Records
)

-- CTE Is left joined because eventually you run out of case counters to join on
SELECT 
R.CaseID
,R.caseCounter 
,R.oldValue  
,R.NewValue AS Name
,changeDate 
,CASE WHEN newDate IS NULL THEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) ELSE NewDate END AS HeldUntil  -- case statement puts today in where you would have a null new date from the left join
,DATEDIFF(DD,changeDate,CASE WHEN newDate IS NULL THEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) ELSE NewDate END) AS DaysHeld -- date diff between change (i.e. start date) and the changeover date
INTO #temp -- place this into a temp table
FROM #Records AS R
LEFT JOIN cte    AS C
    ON r.CaseID = C.CaseID
        AND r.caseCounter = C.caseCounter - 1;



-- simple summary result set from the above
SELECT
CaseID
,Name
,SUM(DaysHeld) AS DaysHeld
FROM #temp
GROUP BY CaseID
,Name
ORDER BY CaseID, Name ASC;
```

Comment: You should really include some explanation of what you are doing in the code. Code-only answers are no good.

Comment: Nicarus Fair enough, edited with comments.  If that is your downvote please remove.

Comment: @TJB, first thank you- when i run the results of your SQL it returns data that is not accurate. for example on caseID 399547 for Eric your SQL has 14 days . but eric initially had the case starting 9/18 and it was assigned to joni on 9/19 so that is 1 day, Eric got the case back 9/25 and sent to "team" on 9/30 so there is another 5 days. so the total should be 6 where it is now returning 14

Comment: The error is that `oldValue` is being used (as `Name`) instead of `NewValue`

Comment: obaidul khandaker  I misunderstood the data and grouped on the wrong name, edited- please try again.

Comment: @TJB - I cleaned up your `INSERT` statement (removed redundant code). If you put a simple summary atop this answer explaining at a high-level what your code does, I would be happy to vote up.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. hopefully my next question will be better formated and put together. thank you again

Comment: @Nicarus short summary added too.

Comment: @TJB - Good answer now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**This is a comment / question, but too long to be placed in the comment section.**

---

I don't understand your expected outcome.

This is the data for case 399547:

```
CaseId   CaseCounter   OldValue   NewValue   ChangeDate
399547   1             Brad       Eric       9/18/2016
399547   2             Meghan     Joni       9/19/2016
399547   3             Eric       Pam        9/20/2016
399547   4             Pam        Meghan     9/22/2016
399547   5             Joni       Eric       9/25/2016
399547   6             Andrea     Team       9/30/2016
399547   7             Team       Admin      10/3/2016
399547   8             Admin      Brad       10/19/2016
399547   9             Eric       Joni       10/21/2016
```

- Eric took over from Brad on September 18 and we don't know how much time Brad had spent on the case.
- Then Pam took over from Eric on September 20, which means that Eric had been working two days on the case then.
- There also was a time when Meghan was on the case and we don't know for how long. However, Joni took over on September 19 and was replaced by Eric on September 25, which is six days later.
- etc.

The data ordered:

```
CaseId   CaseCounter   OldValue   NewValue   ChangeDate
399547   1             Brad       Eric       9/18/2016
399547   3             Eric       Pam        9/20/2016
399547   4             Pam        Meghan     9/22/2016

399547   2             Meghan     Joni       9/19/2016
399547   5             Joni       Eric       9/25/2016
399547   9             Eric       Joni       10/21/2016

399547   6             Andrea     Team       9/30/2016
399547   7             Team       Admin      10/3/2016
399547   8             Admin      Brad       10/19/2016
```

Obviously there have been up to three persons working on the case at the same time.

The total time spent on case 399547 per person:

- Brad: ? + 14 = ?
- Eric: 2 + 26 = 28
- Pam: 2
- Meghan: ? + 11 = ?
- Joni: 6 + 12 = 18
- Andrea: ?
- Team: 3
- Admin: 16

This is very different from your expected outcome. So where am I wrong? By what rule do you get your output?